# How to move text to second col after filling first col?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, overflow

I have two columns here. After vertically filling first column, how to make text continue in second column ? I tried playing with white space, but no use. Any help please.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row w-50">
    <div class="col bg-light ml-5">
      <div>
        <p>a</p>
        <p>b</p>
        <p>c</p>
        <p>d</p>
        <p>e</p>
        <p>f</p>
        <p>g</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col bg-secondary"></div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

```
.col{
        height: 200px;
    }
```

This is current result
[image: Current result is here]

This is required result
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more generic way to do it is to use "flex".
Add " display:flex; flex-direction:column " to the container div and use the "flex-wrap:wrap" property(like the "wrap text" in excel) .

```css
    .flex-container{
        display:flex;
        flex-direction:column;
        flex-wrap:wrap;
        height:200px
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row w-50">
    <div class="col bg-light ml-5">
      <div class="flex-container">
        <p>a</p>
        <p>b</p>
        <p>c</p>
        <p>d</p>
        <p>e</p>
        <p>f</p>
        <p>g</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col bg-secondary"></div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: will not work with an actual text. Insert a real text instead of just letter: https://codepen.io/tacoshy/pen/KKyZpwV

Comment: @tacoshy Those are contact name list.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way to do it is the use of `column-count`-property in combination with `column-fill: auto`. Unfortunatly I have not found any documentation that bootstrap implemented this themself.

```css
div {
  column-count: 2;
  column-fill: auto;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it works.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .col50 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 48.2%;
    margin: 0;
  }
</style>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var columns = 2;
    var size = $("#data > p").size();
    var half = size / columns;
    $(".col50 > p").each(function(index) {
      if (index >= half) {
        $(this).appendTo(".col50:eq(1)");
      }
    });
  });
</script>
<div id="data" class="col50">
  <!-- data Start -->
  <p>This is text 1. </p>
  <p>This is text 2. </p>
  <p>This is text 3. </p>
  <p>This is text 4. </p>
  <p>This is text 5. </p>
  <p>This is text 6. </p>
  <p>This is text 7. </p>
  <p>This is text 8. </p>
  <p>This is text 9. </p>
  <p>This is text 10. </p>
  <p>This is text 11. </p>
  <p>This is text 12. </p>
  <p>This is text 13. </p>
  <p>This is text 14. </p>
  <p>This is text 15. </p>
  <!-- data End-->
</div>
<div class="col50"></div>
```

Comment: text will be dynamic